# Cannot debug Docker self-contained ASP.NET app when using Alpine in VS2022

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dockerfile, visual-studio-2022

When using the Dockerfile (boilerplate from VS) below, I can debug my application in VS2022 with no issue.

```
### Working Dockerfile

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "./MyAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish --runtime linux-musl-x64 --self-contained /p:PublishTrimmed=true /p:PublishSingleFile=true

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyAPI.dll"]
```

I am trying to use the same image use for Production (Alpine) to debug the application locally in Visual Studio but getting an error

```
### Non-working Dockerfile

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:6.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "./MyAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish --runtime linux-musl-x64 --self-contained /p:PublishTrimmed=true /p:PublishSingleFile=true

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs krb5-libs libgcc libintl libssl1.1 libstdc++ zlib
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT  ["./MyAPI"]
```

This is the error I received:

> One or more errors occurred.
>
> Failed to launch debug adapter. Additional information may be available in the output window.
>
> launch: program " does not exist.

I thought I could just change the base image (and add whatever packages is missing in Alpine) and I should be good to go. The idea that I am trying to do is to match the environment I am developing to be as close to the prod environment. What am I missing here?